# How to make visual studio add python to the system path?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to add python to the system path from visual studio/ visual studio installer?

I know it can be manually added to the system path, however I think it's strange that there is no way to add it during install.

I develop in VS2019 but often want to run my scripts separately via command line, on several different machines. Adding python to the path isn't a big deal, but it's one extra step.

[image: Installing python via Visual Studio Installer - no option to add to system path]

[image: "python --version" before and after changing the app execution alias]

Comment: Did you install python globally on your system?

Comment: Just install it globally, it will work.

Comment: What do you mean install it globally? I installed it via VS installer.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio Code, you could go to "Extensions" on the left hand side of the window and type in "Python" within the search box. You will find  the regular "Python", "Python for VSCode v.0.2.3", etc. Each extension has a rating and how many downloads users have done. I would recommend viewing the number of downloads and the rating before downloading, and for me it would be the Python with 4 stars with about 49K downloads, but again, it is completely up to you :)
I wish you well with your journey!!

Comment: I am using Visual studio, not visual studio code. These are different programs.